# Find the determinant of...

Tags: linear-algebra

prove that the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}=0$ for $i=j$ and $a_{ij}=1$ for $i\neq j$ is $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$

I try to prove by induction on $n$. I proved for $n=2.$ Assume the result is true for $n=k.$ 
Now i was struggle to prove for $n=k+1$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=A+I$, so $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with every entry equal to 1.

Then $\text{rank}(B)=1$ and $\text{nullity}(B)=n-1$, so $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ with multiplicity $n-1$; and $\lambda=n$ is an eigenvalue of B with multiplicity 1 since $Bv=nv$ where $v$ is the vector with every entry 1.

Therefore the eigenvalues of $A=B-I$ are given by $\lambda=-1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $\lambda=n-1$ (with multiplicity 1); so

$\det(A)=\lambda_{1}\cdots\lambda_{n}=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1).$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the recursive definition of the determinant, you'll find that one of the recursive determinants is multiplied by zero, the rest by $\pm 1$. For induction to work, each recursive determinant, after a column-shuffle, should look like the size-$n$ case of your claim. But if you look at the $3 \times 3$ case, you'll see that it doesn't. That suggests that the inductive approach, at least the most direct one, isn't going to work. I think you need to look for a different approach.